# curl cant connecto local xampp via ip static

Tags: php, curl, static, xampp, ip

I have installed XAMPP on my Windows with static IP. I want to reach it via internet from another computer with my static IP.
but there is a problem when I try to connect to XAMPP via IP. 
it seems my request is blocked and I get this error:

> "Couldn't connect to server"

I have already disabled my firewall on my Windows.
but I can reach my XAPMP via curl from another host.
there is a tip: when I try it on my local computer form another computer anything is smooth but when I try form online server I get the mentioned error.■■ Connection refused.

Comment: you are trying to access a computer on your local network from the internet - is that correct?

Comment: yes.  i have use form port_forward and i can open my web page from ip static , but i cant use Curl from host to local xampp. i get 

    "Couldn't connect to server"

Comment: can you add the curl related code that you are using to try to access your computer from the interwebs?

Comment: `$curl = new Curl();
        $DATA_POST_Param = [];
        $response = $curl->setPostParams([
            'params' => json_encode($DATA_POST_Param)
        ])
           ->setOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)
            ->post("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx");


        if ($curl->errorCode === null) {
            print_r($response);

        } else {
           echo  $curl->errorText;

        }`

Comment: That code abstracts the real curl code so it's very hard to tell if there is a problem with any of the actual curl settings that are set within `Curl()`

Comment: the problem its not about CURL , its about local xampp server, i can reach it via internet and postman but when i want use CURL i get mentioned error . i think my request blocked.

Comment: when i use CURL form ssh in my linux host , i get same error .

Comment: If you can reach the computer using other methods OK but not when using curl that suggests to me, in my ignorance, that the issue lies with curl not the server config.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `port_forward` your computer to your router to access it via internet.

You are better off using a virtual station for convenience.

Comment: i aleady did it. i can open web page via internet with ip address. but the problem is when i want use of CURL form my host to local xampp .

Comment: Try to open port:80 outbound and inbound. And mysql port if you are using mysql.

Comment: port:80 is ban from my isp , and i have changed default port "80" to other . and i disabled my firewall. but when i want use curl form host to my local xampp it seems block my reques

Comment: Check the configuration again make use your computer and its port is correctly accepting by the router. Make sure to ping it, if it is linux try to scan for open ports or something similar scanning tools for windows.

Also the isp maybe not allowing you to do something like that. Try other services like dydns or something similar.

Comment: config is correct , and i use windows for xampp , i can open web page via ip address right now from my borwser . but i can not connec to that with curl.i set  outbound and inbound on my firewall but nothings change. i disabled my firewall but its not work .